# get запрос в header

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Добрый вечер, нужно отправить get запрос на сервер и положить в заголовок следующее.

Authorization: Bearer rsNQgkedqLca

где rsNQgkedqLca - токен.

Как пытаюсь решить данную проблему:

```
@GET("/get-free-request-count")
Call<Count> getCount(@Header("Authorization") String  token);

Call<Count> call = (Call<Count>) mServerApi.getCount("Bearer " + mToken);
                call.enqueue(new Callback<Count>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<Count> call, Response<Count> response) {
                        if (response.body().getmCount().equals("2")) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "У вас осталось: " + response.body().getmCount(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
```

Что я не так делаю?

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String ru.balodyarecordz.autoexpert.model.Count.getmCount()' on a null object reference

Comment: Всё правильно делаете. А может и нет. Но как мы узнаем, если вы не сообщаете чем кончаются ваши попытки...

Comment: @ЮрийСПб вот, обновил.

Comment: Согласно вашей ошибке у вас `response.body()` `null`. Попробуйте вывести респонс (или его внутренние части) как строку - может там есть какая-то полезная инфа

Comment: @ЮрийСПб нет ничего)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб и что мне делать?

Comment: Попробуйте просто через OkHttp запрос сделать и посмотреть что получится - может с ретрофитом у вас чего.